# How to map values from json to angular view(html) input text tags?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular js -1.2

I have a html page which is having input type =text

```
<input type="text" ng-model="todo.policy.polno"  size="16"
         placeholder="policy no" ng-value="{{todo.policy.polno}}">
```

my DATA looks like this

```
  $scope.todo= [
    {
  "policy": {
    "polno": "VPC000111568954",
    "product code": "VPC",
    "date": "17/02/1990",
........
    }
    ]
```

on load i want to display "VPC000111568954" in textbox1 "vpc" in textbox2 etc 
there are many text boxes and and i have object inside object also in JSON

Answer (score 1):

The code your provided looks correct, since you only provided some of your code there is no way to tell where exactly the problem is. Since `todo` is an array are you making sure to use the `ngRepeat` to iterate through it. It should look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in todo">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.policy.polno"  size="16" placeholder="policy no" /> 
</div>
```

Note there is no need for `ngValue` that directive is for checkboxes and radio buttons.

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/dzATm/